# editing in arraylist with multiple strings

Tags: java, arraylist

I have made a program...
in which I scan 3 different strings and then convert them into a single string using toString() then I put that string into array list
for example 
"name phonenumber addrees"
it works fine....the problem is when i have to edit it...
i use string.split to split them and edit them...
but i dont know what is wrong..whenever i try to edit it goes to exception error...can anyone help me out?
PROBLEM IN CASE 3 of first switch

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> arraylist= new ArrayList<String>();
    CreateFormat FormatObject = new CreateFormat();

    int choice;
    String phoneNumber;
    String name,address;
    String format="Empty";
    int x=1;
    int flag=0;



    do
    {

    try

    {   
    System.out.println("Enter your choice");
    System.out.printf("1:Enter new data\n2:Display data");
    choice=Integer.parseInt(input.next());
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        System.out.println("Enter name  ");
        name=input.next();
        System.out.println("Enter phone number");
        phoneNumber=input.next();
        System.out.println("Enter address");
        address=input.next();
        format=FormatObject.toString(phoneNumber, name, address); // will merge these 3 Strings with space in between
        arraylist.add(format);
        flag++;


    }
        break;
    case 2:
    {
        System.out.println("Name   Phone number   Address");
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0;i<flag;i++)
        {   
        System.out.println(arraylist.get(i)); //arraylist cant be displayed on nextline without loop

        }
    }
        break;
    case 3:
        {
        System.out.println("Enter the position you want to edit");
        System.out.println("1:Name\n2:Phone number\n3:Address");
        int choice2;
        choice2=input.nextInt();
        String dupFormat= arraylist.get(choice2-1);
        String[] splitString= dupFormat.split(" ");
         switch (choice2)
         {
         case 1:
         {   System.out.println("Enter new name");
             splitString[0]=input.next();
             break;
         }
         case 2:
         {   System.out.println("Enter new phone number");
             splitString[1]=input.next();
         }
             break;
         case 3:
         {   System.out.println("Enter new Address");
             splitString[2]=input.next();
         }
         break;
         default:
         {   
            System.out.println("Choice is only 1,2,3 ");

         }

         String newFormat=splitString.toString();
         arraylist.add(choice2-1, newFormat);
         }


        }break;

    default:
        System.out.println("Error");
        break;


    }

}

catch(Exception InputMismatchException){
System.out.println("Enter right choice ..");    
}
    }while(x==1);

}}
```

my toString method--->

```
public class CreateFormat {
String phoneNumber;
String nameUser;
String addressUser;
public String toString(){

return String.format("%s %s %s", nameUser,phoneNumber,addressUser);
}
public String toString (String phone,String name,String address){
phoneNumber=phone;
nameUser=name;
addressUser=address;
return String.format("%s %s %s", nameUser,phoneNumber,addressUser);

}
```

}

Comment: Please add the stacktrace of the exception to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this code was the `choice` object..
Because if the input is a wrong input,choice object stays like that forever 
that's there should be two objects for the input

Answer (score 0):

You have `break;` statement outside of your second switch cases. For example you have `break;` outside of

```
case 2:
     {   System.out.println("Enter new phone number");
         splitString[1]=input.next();
     }
         break;
```

And it will break first switch.

So new string won't add into array. And even if you call this

```
String newFormat=splitString.toString();
arraylist.add(choice2-1, newFormat);
```

it will change your data to somthing like `[Ljava.lang.String;@1f7030a6`. It's because you trying to call `toString()` on newly created array from `dupFormat.split(" ")`.

I'd recomended change case 3 section to

```
System.out.println("Enter the position you want to edit");
System.out.println("1:Name\n2:Phone number\n3:Address");
int choice2;
choice2 = input.nextInt();
String dupFormat = arraylist.get(choice2 - 1);
String[] splitString = dupFormat.split(" ");
switch (choice2) {
    case 1: {
        System.out.println("Enter new name");
        FormatObject.nameUser = input.next();
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        System.out.println("Enter new phone number");
        FormatObject.phoneNumber = input.next();
        break;
    }
    case 3: {
        System.out.println("Enter new Address");
        FormatObject.addressUser = input.next();
        break;
    }
    default: {
        System.out.println("Choice is only 1,2,3 ");
    }
}
String newFormat = FormatObject.toString();
arraylist.add(choice2 - 1, newFormat);
break;
```

And you will change state of your object and after that you can call `toString()` again with new data.

Answer (score 0):

couldn't find the issue but your code is very hard to read..
Why would you want to store the Name, Phone number and Address as a String?

I would suggest:

1. creating a class that contains those fields.
2. create a function that will implement the code you have in each case (that way you can also test each function seperatly)
3. in the functions work with an instance of the class from (1) and convert to string only when you want to print.
4. I would also get read of the do-while, switch but that is up to you
5. also try to give more meaningful names when you code.. your flag for example is used as a count and not a flag.

so you should do something like this: (and test every function individually)

```
    private List<PersonalData> list = new ArrayList<>();

    ///....

    switch(choise){
        case 1://consider replacing with enum
        {
            list.add(getPersonalDataFromInput());
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            printAll();
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the position you want to edit");
            System.out.println("1:Name\n2:Phone number\n3:Address");
            int choice2;
            choice2=input.nextInt();
            String dupFormat= arraylist.get(choice2-1);
            if(choice2==1){
                list.get(list.size()-1).setName(input.next());
            }
            else if(choice2==2){
                list.get(list.size()-1).setPhone(input.next());
            }
            else (choice2==3){
                list.get(list.size()-1).setAddress(input.next());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and the class to create:

```
class PersonalData{
        private String phoneNumber;
        private String name;
        private String address;
        //getters and setters
    }
```